# __all__ variable not picked up in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `__init__.py` that looks like this

`__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['cooling', 'counters']
```

my directory structure looks like:

```
example_dir/  
    __init__.py  
    cooling.py  
    power.py  
    counters.py
```

When I try to `import example_dir`, python doesn't import `cooling` and `counters`. It imports nothing. Using Pdb, I see that it reads the `__init__.py` but it's refusing to read the `__all__` variable.

I use `imp.load_module` to load the modules

My entire program:

```
def import_module(name, path=None):
    parts = name.split('.')
    module_name = ""
    for index, part in enumerate(parts):
        module_name = part if index == 0 else '%s.%s' % (module_name, part)
        if path is not None:
            path = [path]
        fh, path, descr = imp.find_module(part, path)
        mod = imp.load_module(module_name, fh, path, descr)
    return mod


def load_module(name):
    try:
        mod = None
        mod = sys.modules[name]
    except KeyError:
        mod = import_module(name)
    finally:
        if not mod:
            raise ImportError('unable to import module %s' % name)
        return mod

load_module('example_dir')
```

Comment: `__all__` doesn't have anything to do with importing nested modules inside packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding what `__all__` does ...

In `__init__.py`, you want to actually import the modules you want.  e.g.

```
# __init__.py
import example_dir.cooling as cooling
import example_dir.counters as counters
```

`__all__` on the other hand says what names in the current module should be imported when the user writes `from ... import *`.

In short, `__all__` has nothing to do with what *modules* get imported, only what *names* are available after a module is imported (and then, only if the user is importing *everything* from a module).

Comment: Thanks. I think I misunderstood the purpose of \__all__

So my question then would be, what do I do to achieve my desired result? If I want to say load_module('example_dir') and have only cooling imported in?

add a from example_dir import * ??